# SQL UPDATE works in MySQL fails in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have the following query:

`UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '13'; UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '15';`

If I try that directly in in MySQL it works as expected.

When I try it via PHP it gives me the following error:

```
Error: UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '13'; UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '15';
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '15'' at line 1
```

I get a feeling it has to do with the quotations but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Submit code:

```
$query = "UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '13'; UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '15';";

$db = $conn;
$execute = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if ($execute==true) {
  $success = 1;
} else {
  echo  "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
}
```

Table `names`:

```
name_id     name    rsvp_status
13          John    0
15          David   0
17          Bill    1
..
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use update in batch in php, and an update is a query.

Comment: In order to learn... why not? And what would be a solution?

Comment: You can change your query to this 
UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id in ('13','15')

Comment: @Xun Thanks but how would that look if if the values are not both the same? For example UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '0' WHERE name_id = '13'; UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '15';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're submitting more than one query in the SQL:

1. `UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '13';`
2. `UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '15';`

You can technically run multiple queries at once using `[mysqli::multi_query][1]` but it's generally a dangerous idea... you're almost always better off running the queries in a loop in a situation like this:

```
$db = $conn;
$queries = [
    "UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '13';",
    "UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id = '15';"
];

foreach($queries as $query){
      $execute = mysqli_query($db, $query);
      if ($execute==true) {
          $success = 1;
      } else {
          echo  "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
          break; //you probably want to stop if mysql is erroring
      }
}
```

As someone commented above, you can also simplify this into a single query (`UPDATE names SET rsvp_status = '1' WHERE name_id IN ( '13',15);`) but assuming you might have different values for `rsvp_status` or otherwise need multiple queries, I'd recommend that loop.

You should also make sure you're escaping your values if you're not planning on hard-coding them like the example (you're almost certainly not going to hard-code those values) and your error handling could be cleaned up a bit, but otherwise this is a better approach.

Comment: After I post the question I realized it was because of the multiple queries. Your solution makes perfect sense (and works in my case). And yes, the values are not hardcoded, I just skipped all that to simplify the question. Thanks for the help, always good to learn something :-)